# correct terminology

Tags: logic

A corollary is a theorem that follows almost trivially from the RESULT of a previous theorem.  Similarly there is another name for a theorem that follows almost trivially from the LOGIC of the proof of an earlier theorem, rather than from the RESULT.  Many people mistakenly call this theorem a corollary, but it is not.  There is another name for this thing, but I forgot what it is.  What is it?

Comment: Do you mean when the proof is analogous?

Comment: The expression *corollary to the proof* is not uncommon.